# I have to write a for loop to print the ASCII values of chars which are in an array

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, ascii

This is what I have so far. I'm unsure how to print the individual value of each char in ascii without the values repeating on every line. Any help would be appreciated.

> Create    a   for loop to print   out all of  the ASCII   values  associated  with    EACH
> character   of  the town    name    or  pet name (e.g., R   =   125,    a   =   97  etc.)

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Lab1Part2{

    public static void main (String[] args){

    char B = 'B';
    char l = 'l';
    char a = 'a';
    char n  ='n';
    char h = 'h';
    int ascii = B;

        //create array
        char[] JavaCharArray = new char[6];
        JavaCharArray[0] = 'B';
        JavaCharArray[1] = 'l';
        JavaCharArray[2] = 'a';
        JavaCharArray[3] = 'n';
        JavaCharArray[4] = 'c';
        JavaCharArray[5] = 'h';

        //print array
        for(int i=0;i<JavaCharArray.length;i++){
            System.out.println(JavaCharArray[i] + " = " + ascii);
             }



         }
        }
```

Comment: In Java naming conventions, `JavaCharArray` should be `javaCharArray`.

Comment: Can you explain why have you written `R = 125`? The ASCII value for `R` is `82`...

Answer (score 2):

The `char` type in Java is legacy, essentially broken. As a [16-bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/16-bit_computing) value, it is incapable of representing most characters.

## Code points

Instead, learn to use [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers to work with individual characters.

```
int[] codePoints = "Blanch".codePoints().toArray() ;
for( int codePoint : codePoints ) 
{
    System.out.println( "character: " + Character.toString( codePoint ) + " = code point: " + codePoint ) ;
}
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/2E89OM).

```
character: B = code point: 66
character: l = code point: 108
character: a = code point: 97
character: n = code point: 110
character: c = code point: 99
character: h = code point: 104
character:  = code point: 128567
```

You will find "codePoint" related methods around various classes such as `String`, `Character`, `StringBuilder`. See also: [*The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the characters to `int`:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

        //create array
        char[] JavaCharArray = new char[6];
        JavaCharArray[0] = 'B';
        JavaCharArray[1] = 'l';
        JavaCharArray[2] = 'a';
        JavaCharArray[3] = 'n';
        JavaCharArray[4] = 'c';
        JavaCharArray[5] = 'h';

        //print array
        System.out.print("(");
        for (int i = 0; i < JavaCharArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(JavaCharArray[i] + " = " + (int) JavaCharArray[i]+ ", ");
        }
        System.out.print(")");


    }
```

Comment: Thank you Flav, worked perfectly

Comment: This code fails to compile with most characters. See [example at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/80CH3S).

Comment: In your example you tried to get the ascii value of an emoji which is not possible since ASCII only supports 128 different characters.

Comment: @Flav Java supports Unicode, a superset of US-ASCII. The `char` type became obsolete with the release of Java 2.

Comment: @Basil Bourque, I didn’t know about code points, thanks for the explanation :). Bkavo123 asked for Ascii but I didn’t know there was a better way

Comment: @Flav You will find "codePoint" related methods around various classes such as `String`, `Character`, `StringBuilder`. See also: [*The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate "ascii" every time you enter the loop (iteration). char can be casted to int automatically

```
//print array
for(int i=0; i<JavaCharArray.length; i++){
    ascii =  JavaCharArray[i];
    System.out.println( JavaCharArray[i] + " = " + ascii);
}
```

btw: you declare a few char variables at the start but never use them. For example, you probably wanted to do `JavaCharArray[0] = B;` rather than `JavaCharArray[0] = 'B';`